# How to choose a golf club for beginners with at least cost?

Tags: golf

I'm just begin interested in golf, so i'm intend buy one golf club but I don't have the experience to choose. What are my options?

Comment: Are you sure you want to start that badly? Learning golf with just one club is impossible. if you don't want to spend too much money just buy a used set. And you should consider taking lessons. Golf isn't really learning by doing.

Comment: Does this question help? https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/992/how-can-i-get-started-in-golf

Answer (score -1):

You cannot play golf with just one club.  You need a fairway club and a putter. For a new player I would go with like an 8 iron and a putter.

Many golf shops have a used bin.

You can find whole golf sets in resale shops cheap.

Driving ranges often have loaner clubs.